# Is there a transitive set of finite sets with cardinality > $ℵ$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

edit: Is there a transitive set of finite sets with cardinality > $2^{ℵ_0}$?

Comment: What do you mean when you write $\aleph$? Is it $2^{\aleph_0}$? Is it something else?

Comment: Is the context $\sf ZF$ or $\sf ZFC$, or some other set theory?

Comment: I ment 2^(א0) sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. To see this, observe that if $A$ is a transitive set all of whose elements are finite, then every element of $A$ is in fact hereditarily finite, meaning that every element of its transitive closure is finite. But there are only countably many hereditarily finite sets (they are precisely the elements of $V_\omega$ in the von Neumann hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

If we allow urelements then yes. Urelements are just elements of sets that are not themselves sets, so it is easy to form a set of urelements which is greater than any cardinal, by considering symbols, say, of which there are $\aleph$ many. Each set is finite, because it contains only one element - its urelement.